# Understand "i-Equivalent Valuation" that satisfies formula

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

From the book *Logic for Mathematicians* (A. G. Hamilton):

> Definition 3.19
>
> Two valuations $v$ and $v'$ are $i$-equivalent if $v(x_j)=v'(x_j)$ for all $j\neq i$.

(I know every single book out there have a different way to define this.)

Then consider $A= (\forall x_1)(\exists x_2) P(x_1,f(x_2))$ under the interpretation $\cal I$ with domain $\mathbb{Z}$, and $P(x_1,x_2)$ means $x_1=x_2$, and $f(x)=x+1$.

It is easy to see that $A$ is true for $\cal I$, but my goal is to write the proof in a more or less formal way (similar to the one that is handled in the same book).

This is what I have now:

> Consider $v$ to be a valuation in $\cal I$, then $v(x_1), v(x_2) \in \mathbb{Z}$ and we interpret $P(x_1,f(x_2))$ as $v(x_1)=v(x_2)+1$ which is true for $v(x_1)=2$ and $v(x_2)=1$. Now we start to consider $i$-equivalent valuations.
> So for every valuation $v'$ 1-equivalent to $v$, there always exists a valuation $v'$ 2-equivalent to $v$ in which $v'(x_1)=v'(x_2)+1$.

I don't know if that's OK, and really I don't know if I'm understanding  valuations well at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've grasped the concept of valuations.  As you've noted, not every presentation of interpretations for first-order logic does this exactly the same way.  The Wikipedia article on interpretations in logic has a section [interpretations of a first-order language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_%28logic%29#Interpretations_of_a_first-order_language), and you'll notice that they first describe the easy-to-grasp intuition of how to understand whether an interpretation satisfies $\forall x.\phi(x)$ and $\exists x.\phi(x)$.

> This leaves the issue of how to interpret formulas of the form ∀ x φ(x) and ∃ x φ(x). The domain of discourse forms the range for these quantifiers. The idea is that the sentence ∀ x φ(x) is true under an interpretation exactly when every substitution instance of φ(x), where x is replaced by some element of the domain, is satisfied. The formula ∃ x φ(x) is satisfied if there is at least one element d of the domain such that φ(d) is satisfied. — [Interpretations of a first-order language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(logic)#Interpretations_of_a_first-order_language)

The problem arises however, that we can't actually talk about $\phi(d)$, because that isn't actually a formula:

> Strictly speaking, a substitution instance such as the formula φ(d) mentioned above is not a formula in the original formal language of φ, because d is an element of the domain. There are two ways of handling this technical issue. The first is to pass to a larger language in which each element of the domain is named by a constant symbol. The second is to add to the interpretation a function that assigns each variable to an element of the domain. Then the T-schema can quantify over variations of the original interpretation in which this variable assignment function is changed, instead of quantifying over substitution instances. — [Interpretations of a first-order language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretation_(logic)#Interpretations_of_a_first-order_language)

The definition given by Hamilton follows the second of these options. It does mean, however, that we no longer get to speak of an interpretation $\cal I$ satisfying a formula, but we have to speak of $\cal I$ and a valuation $v$ satisfying a formula.  The alternative is to include a valuation $v$ inside an interpretation, but we still end up having to say that $\cal I = (D,\dots,v)$ (where $\dots$ is everything else that is in the interpretation) satisfies $\forall x.\phi(x)$ if and only if every $\cal I' = (D,\dots,v')$ satisfies $\forall x.\phi(x)$, where $v'$ differs from $v'$ only on $x$.  This amounts to the same thing, but with more syntax.

Your proof is in pretty good shape as it is, I think.  You could express some things a bit more rigorously, perhaps, but the intuition and general structure is correct.  Since you're defining the domain to be $\mathbb{Z}$ and can reference mathematical functions in your semantic explanation, I think you can do something like the following.  Since you are interpreting $P$ as the equality function on $\mathbb{Z}$ and $f$ as $+1$, I simply used equality in the following formula, and $s$ as the successor ($+1$) function.

> Interpretation $\cal I$ and valuation $v$ satisfy $\forall x_1.\exists x_2.(x_1 = s(x_2))$ if and only if $\cal I$ and *every* 1-equivalent valuation $v'$ satisfy $\exists x_2.(x_1 = s(x_2))$.  The interpretation $\cal I$ and valuation $v'$ satisfy $\exists x_2.(x_1 = s(x_2))$ if and only if there is *some* valuation $v''$ that is 2-equivalent to $v'$ such that $\cal I$ and $v''$ satisfy $x_1 = s(x_2)$.
>
> Consider an arbitrary valuation $v$.  Let $v'$ be an arbitary valuation that is 1-equivalent to $v$.  Then let $n = v'(x_1)$. Let $v''$ be the valuation that agrees with $v'$ on every value except $x_2$, which it maps to $n-1$.  Observe that $\cal I$ and $v''$ satisfy $x_1 = s(x_2)$.  Then, since there is *some* valuation (viz., $v''$) that is 2-equivalent to $v'$ which, with $\cal I$, satisfies $x_1 = s(x_2)$, then $\cal I$ and $v'$ satisfy $\exists x_2.(x_1 = s(x_2))$.  Then, since $v'$ is an arbitrary valuation 1-equivalent to $v$, *every* valuation 1-equivalent to $v$, with $\cal I$, satisfies $\exists x_2.(x_1 = s(x_2))$, so $\cal I$ and $v$ satisfy $\forall x_1.\exists x_2.(x_1 = s(x_2))$.

Comment: There have been some other questions and answers that have included discussion of first order interpretations.  The last few paragraphs of [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/377682/72995) about the meaning of symbols (e.g., unbound variables) in Fitch-style proofs discuss interpretations, as does a section in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/413322/72995) about proving sentences based on their semantics.

Comment: I only used $v$ and $v'$, you added $v''$. Well, i think i understand the proof, the concept about it, but what is more difficult to understand is the "syntax" used. Let me correct mi proof... when i consider $v'$ 1-equivalent to $v$, then if i want to consider another situacion inside this $v'$ (in this case about $x_2$) i need to refer to $v''$ 2-equivalent $v'$ ??.

Comment: Another question, ¿is really needed to say: "$v′′$ be the valuation that agrees with $v′$ on every value except $x_2$" ?, i tought that was clarified when you say "$v''$ 2-equivalent  to $v'$" so the only value to be changed from $v'$ is $x_2$.

Comment: @Wyvern666 To first comment: Suppose we ask whether interpretation $\cal I$ and valuation $v$ satisfy formula $\forall x.\exists y.\phi(x,y)$. Then we first consider whether _every_ $v'$ that is $x$-equivalent to $v$ satisfies $\exists y.\phi(y)$.  For each $v'$, we ask whether $\cal I, v'$ satisfy $\exists y.\phi(x,y)$; i.e., whether there is _some_ $v''$ that is $y$-equivalent to $v'$ such that $\cal I, v''$ satisfy $\phi(x,y)$.  All the $v'$ give us all the possible valuations for $x$, and for each one, $v''$ provides the particular value of $y$.

Comment: @Wyvern666 To second comment:  I wrote “let $v''$ be the valuation that agrees…” because I wanted to highlight that we can _construct_ the particular $v''$ that we need, and then _observe_ that is 2-equivalent to $v'$ (which we need for the semantics of $\exists x_2.\phi(x)$).  It's probably OK to just say, “let $v''$ be the value that is 2-equivalent to $v'$ and that maps $x_2$ to $n-1$.”

Comment: Now im getting it. This means that if i have more vars suppose $\forall x,\exists y,\exists z$, then is probable that i will end up working with $v,v',v'',v'''$ valuations in order to make a valid proof. So depending on the case i will have just one or maybe n valuations to consider?

Comment: @Wyvern666 Well, if you try to keep up this level of rigor, you will.  In practice it's more common (and easier) to just say, “$\forall x.\exists y.(x = y+1)$ is true because $x$ must be some value $n$ from $\mathbb{Z}$, and for each such $n$, $n-1$ is a suitable $y$.  It's interesting how informal the formal logicians are. :)

Comment: Your explanations are excelent. Thanks.

Comment: More on this topic, when dealing with negated cuantifiers, ¿is more convenient to express them in some equivalent not negated form in order to make the proof?.

Comment: @Wyvern666 I think it very much depends on what the end goal is.  $\exists$ and $\forall$ are duals, as are $\lor$ and $\land$.  We can ask whether it's more convenient to have $\lnot(p \lor q)$ or $\lnot p \land \lnot q$, but the answer depends on what we're trying to prove.

Comment: Yes i understand what you mean. But, for example, if you have $\lnot \forall x P(x)$, so i need to find every valuation x-equivalent that NOT satisfies P(x)?. I think is more intuitive to find what satisfies and not the other way.. Maybe i just need more practice.